# In MySql how do I add missing decimals to the currency column?

Tags: mysql, decimal

I don't want a currency symbol, but I have values like;

```
4900
4900
4900
4900
5100
5100
5100
5100
5100
5100
5100
5100
5100
4500
```

I want to be able to make them `49.00`, `51.00` and `45.00` respectively.

How can I do this in MySQL, if possible? It is ok to assume that ALL values in the column of 4500 records can use the decimal 2 places in from the right.

Comment: divide by 100? `SELECT money/100 FROM yourGlaringTable;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason dividing by 100 won't do what you need?  See below:

(EDIT - As pointed out in Brian's answer, casting is probably best)

```
mysql> select * from testTable;
+---------+
| testNum |
+---------+
|    4900 | 
|    4900 | 
|    4900 | 
|    5100 | 
+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select ROUND(CAST(testNum AS DECIMAL)/100,2) from testTable;
+---------------------------------------+
| ROUND(CAST(testNum AS DECIMAL)/100,2) |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                 49.00 | 
|                                 49.00 | 
|                                 49.00 | 
|                                 51.00 | 
+---------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

should be able to divide by 100 but it may depend on the data type of the field.  if It isn't set with a precision then you will have to cast the field as a decimal and then divide by 100 like so.

```
CAST('field' AS DECIMAL(10,2))/100
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.123456, 4);
        -> '12,332.1235'
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.1,4);
        -> '12,332.1000'
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.2,0);
        -> '12,332'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `column` = ROUND(`column`/100, 2)
WHERE 1
```